# How can I have 2 or more spring applications in one code base?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a springboot web application, and I want to build a spring console application for utility purposes, so I have two clases with a main static method to start, the command line app is like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Maintf implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final AService aserviceInstance;

    @Autowired
    public Maintf(AService service) {
        this.aserviceInstance = service;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication m = (new SpringApplicationBuilder(Maintf.class)).web(false).build();
        m.run();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        for (Account a : aserviceInstance.getAccounts() ) {
            System.out.println(a.getId());
        }
    }

}
```

But when i run it tries to instantiate everything that Im not using (Controllers, configurations , and others services) even the web application container (tomcat) and fails, I just want to execute some service in the same code base. The service Im trying to inject does not have any dependencies on other components.
How can i prevent spring to instantiate like a web app?

Comment: How does it fail? does it throw an exception? could you post the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to the entire Application to get started up, you could just let the current SpringBootApplication to scan the necessary packages (in this the required services package)

Forexample:

**Application1**

com.app.app1

com.app.app1.services

-->service1

-->service2

SpringBootApplication1

**Application2**

com.app.app2

com.app.app2.services

-->service1

-->service2

SpringBootApplication2

**currentApplication**

com.app.currentApp

com.app.currentApp.services

-->service1

-->service2

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {"com.app.app1.services", "com.app.app2.services"})
CurrentSpringBootApplication

By this way you could just let the Springboot to scan the necessary packages and let to autowire in your app.